# SAP BODS : XML export and alias names

Tags: xml, sap-data-services

I exported my BODS job into XML format. I wanted to check the error tables in the bulk loading properties, I found the teradata_errortable1 and teradata_errortable2 tags for that.

My issue is that even though I mentioned the ALIAS names in the Bulk Loading options for the error tables, the xml shows always the actual database name instead of the alias.

Is this behavior normal, and the alias names always get substituted while exporting?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are checking in the correct tag and you have mentioned ALIAS, reason being I performed a quick test and whatever is referenced in table template is getting reflected in the xml export. Please find below screenshots:

With Substitution Parameter
[image]

With Alias
[image]

Cheers.
Shaz